# How to set Alarm Tone from My Application using AlarmManager?

Tags: android

How to set Alarm Tone from My Application using AlarmManager?

My RingTonePicker Method:-

```
private void startRing()
{
   Intent i = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
   startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SET_RINGTONE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data )
{
    switch (resultCode) {
        case RESULT_OK:
            Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            Log.i("Sample", "uri " + uri);
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, uri);
                 break;
           }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

My BroadCast Receiver Method:-

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Vibrate the mobile phone
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
            .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);
}
```

The Problem is Only Vibrator is vibrating no Ringtone is Playing.

Please Help Me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this -

```
Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
mp= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), alert);
mp.setVolume(100, 100);
mp.start();
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
mp.release();
}
});

vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService (VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(400);
```

Comment: Suchi.. Really its a quite easy way to get Audio and Vibration. thanks